# first/count applied to groupby returns empty dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( {'A': [1,1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,7,7,8]} )
dummy = df["A"]
print(dummy)

0     1
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5
6     5
7     6
8     7
9     7
10    7
11    8
Name: A, dtype: int64

res = df.groupby(dummy)
print(res.first())

Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Why the last print results in an empty dataframe? I except each group to be a slice of the original df, where each slice would contain as many rows as the number of duplicates for a given value in column "A". What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is by default, `A` is set to index before applying the groupby operator (e.g. `first`). Therefore, `df` is essentially empty before the actual `first` operator is applied. If you have another column `B`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'A': [1,1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,7,7,8], 'B':range(12)} )
```

then you would see `A` as the index and the first values for `B` in each group with `df.groupby(dummy).first()`:

```
    B
A    
1   0
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   7
7   8
8  11
```

On the other note, if you force `as_index=False`, `groupby` would not set `A` as index and you would have the non-empty data:

```
df.groupby(dummy, as_index=False).first()
```

gives:

```
   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
5  6
6  7
7  8
```

Or, you can groupby on a **copy** of the column:

```
df.groupby(dummy.copy()).first()
```

and you get:

```
   A
A   
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
5  5
6  6
7  7
8  8
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but why (in your first example) the values of column B are lost? And could you please elaborate on why copying the column (second example) solves the problem?

Comment: With only a single column in your DataFrame, groupby() function takes the column 'A' in `res = df.groupby(dummy)` and makes it the ***Index*** of your new DataFrame `res` with no values to show, because it has no more columns of values. What the copy function did was it made another copy of column 'A'. So when the original column 'A' was passed in `groupby()`, it was converted to Index values and the copy was taken as Data.

Comment: Hmm, but shouldn't column A, that is passed as first parameter to groupby, be used just for mapping an index label (in this case 0, 1, 2, ... 11) to the corresponding group name (1, ..., 8) ? Passing a copy of column A leads to different result with respect to using as_index = False when the dataframe contains more than one column

Answer (score 1):

By default, `as_index` is `True` which means it will take the passed column and make it the index and then group the other columns of DataFrame accordingly. You need to make `as_index=False` to get your desired results.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( {'A': [1,1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,7,7,8]} )
dummy = df["A"]
print(dummy)


res = df.groupby(dummy,as_index=False)
print(res.first())

   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
5  6
6  7
7  8
```

`as_index` : bool, default True

> For aggregated output, return object with group labels as the index. Only relevant for DataFrame input. as_index=False is effectively “SQL-style” grouped output.